# libgdx dragging & placing actors

Tags: java, libgdx, actor, movable

I'm stuck on making widgets grab-able / movable & I was hoping someone here on stack could point me in the direction of achieving this. I Was originally thinking using movement from com.badlogic.gdx.scene.scene2d.ui.Window & was curious if there was an easier way. I've looked into all the methods inherited from other classes on GDXwiki & still have no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is Box2D's QueryAABB method.

Comment: Also, I forgot, stage.hit(x, y) to get the first actor hit in a coordinate.